# How to deconvolve from the result of a sort of double convolution integral?

Tags: calculus, statistics, probability-distributions, convolution

Say that I have a probability density function defined on the unit circle, $f_{\Theta}(\theta)$, with $\theta \in \left[0,2\pi\right)$. I have a joint pdf, assuming independence, of $f_{\Theta_1,\Theta_2,\Theta_3}(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)=f_{\Theta}(\theta_1) f_{\Theta}(\theta_2) f_{\Theta}(\theta_3)$. I also have the following transformations: $\theta_{12}=\theta_2-\theta_1$, and $\theta_{23}=\theta_3-\theta_2$. Using these transformations, I rewrite the joint pdf as:

$$f_{\Theta_{12},\Theta_2,\Theta_{23}}(\theta_{12},\theta_2,\theta_{23})=f_{\Theta}(\theta_2-\theta_{12}) f_{\Theta}(\theta_2) f_{\Theta}(\theta_2+\theta_{23})$$

I integrate out the dependence on $\theta_2$ to arrive at:

$$f_{\Theta_{12},\Theta_{23}}(\theta_{12},\theta_{23})=\int_{0}^{2\pi} f_{\Theta}(\theta_2-\theta_{12}) f_{\Theta}(\theta_2) f_{\Theta}(\theta_2+\theta_{23}) \text{d}\theta_2$$

This is a sort of double convolution, the original function is being convolved with two copies of itself each shifted in opposite directions by independent amounts ($\theta_{12}$ and $\theta_{23}$ respectively).

**Here is my question:** I have $f_{\Theta_{12},\Theta_{23}}(\theta_{12},\theta_{23})$ and would like to recover $f_{\Theta}(\theta)$, how can I do this?

Comment: What happens if you apply the Fourier transform to everything?

Comment: @RahulNarain: I get, if I'm not mistaken, the following:

$$\hat{f}_{\Theta_{12},\Theta_{23}}(k_{12},k_{23})={\hat{f}}_{\Theta}^{*}(k_{12}) {\hat{f}}_{\Theta}(k_{23}) {\hat{f}}_{\Theta}(k_{12}-k_{23})$$

Where the star indicates complex conjugation, and the hats indicate the fourier transform. This is just a form of the convolution theorem, but I'm still unclear about how to deconvolute from there.

Comment: Assuming that's right, you immediately have $\hat{f}_{\Theta_{12},\Theta_{23}}(k,k) = {\hat{f}}_{\Theta}^{*}(k​) {\hat{f}}_{\Theta}(k) {\hat{f}}_{\Theta}(0) = \big\lvert\hat{f}_{\Theta}(k​)\big\rvert^2 {\hat{f}}_{\Theta}(0)$, so at the very least you can recover the amplitude of $\hat{f}_{\Theta}(k​)$ up to scaling by $\hat f_\Theta(0)$. Let $k=0$ and you fix $\hat f_\Theta(0)$ too. Probably there's more.

Comment: @RahulNarain: That's a great step in the right direction, but still leaves the phase unknown. Another piece of information is that these functions are strictly real (they're pdfs) so we have:
$${\hat{f}}_{\Theta}(-k)={\hat{f}}_{\Theta}^{*}(k)$$
But this still doesn't seem to uniquely define the phase.

Comment: It's quite possible that the integration over $\theta_2$ eliminates information about phase. After all, phase encodes translation, while $\theta_{12}$ and $\theta_{23}$ are translation-invariant...

Comment: What do you mean about $\theta_{12}$ and $\theta_{23}$ being translation-invariant?